# My distribution has etags symlinked to ctags, but where can I get original etags?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, software-installation, apt, ctags

That's weird that I completely failed to google this question.

The situation is ridiculous: Linux Mint 17.2 (almost the same as Ubuntu 14.04) has `etags` as a symlink to `ctags`. But actually, as we can see in man pages, they are not identical:

- [etags man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/etags)
- [ctags man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ctags)

I have a foreign project, whose build process depends on `etags`' option `--declarations`. Ctags doesn't appear to have such option, so, the command fails.

So I need for original `etags` program, and, surprisingly enough, I failed to find it. Could anyone please help?

Comment: Some programs change their behavior based on their called name ($0), such as busy box. Does running `etags --declarations` work?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Sadly no, the build process contains command `etags -o - --declarations /path/to/file` , and it complains: `etags: Unknown option: --declarations`

Comment: @JeffSchaller, got it solved, finally! (see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

Finally, the user `jim` from `##linux` on `irc.freenode.net` helped me:

```
$ sudo aptitude install emacs24-bin-common
```

After this, real `etags` is installed. These Ubuntu's alternatives could be very confusing though...

And, for similar problems, possible solution is to use `apt-file` utility:

```
$ sudo aptitude install apt-file
$ apt-file update
```

Then, look for the file you need:

```
$ apt-file find /bin/etags
```

The output for `/bin/etags` is:

```
emacs23-bin-common: /usr/bin/etags.emacs23
emacs24-bin-common: /usr/bin/etags.emacs24
xemacs21-bin: /usr/bin/etags.xemacs21
```

So we can pick some package from this list, try to install it, and `update-alternatives` will do its job.